# Dynamically load array values outside of foreach loop into email

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I have a for each loop in which I use to fetch all inventory values of a product if the value is lower than a set amount, I need to send an email to someone. Now how do I approach this in order to not blast multiple emails, but just one?

What I have now is

```
$theme = \Theme::current();
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
$arr = [];

try {
    $resultinventory = $client->request(
        "GET", "api.call.hidden", [
            'auth' => [
                'asfasf',
                'asfasf'
            ]
        ]);

    $body = $resultinventory->getBody();
    $body->seek(0);
    $body->read(1024);
    $inventory = json_decode($body, true);

    foreach($inventory as $i) {
        if ($i['quantityOnHand'] < 10) {
            $resultproduct = $client->request(
                "GET", "api.hidden". $i['productId'], [
                    'auth' => [
                        'asfasf',
                        'asfasf'
                    ]
            ]);

            $bod = $resultproduct->getBody();
            $bod->seek(0);
            $bod->read(1024);
            $product = json_decode($bod, true);
            array_push($arr, $product);
        }
    }

    $emailSubject = "Location A has items running low on stock";
    $emailContents = "Dear Operations Team, Location A is running low on these items:</br>" 
    Mail::to('asf@asf.com')->send(new \App\Mail\SendNotificationEmail($emailSubject, $emailContents, $theme));

    \Log::info($arr);

} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    $err = $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
    \Log::info($err);
    return response()->json(['error' => $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(), 'error_code' => $err]);
}

$this->info('storehub:call is working fine');
```

**Note:** what I want happening is that all values from `$arr` to display on `$emailContents`, in order, so it'll be like; `"Dear Operations team, Location A is running low on these items: 1) Product A, 2)Product B."` and so on.

Array structure:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbdf',
    'name' => 'Diamond bracelet (sample)',
    'tags' => 
    array (
      0 => 'female',
      1 => 'jewelry',
    ),
    'category' => 'Accessories',
    'sku' => '1029EHW',
    'priceType' => 'Fixed',
    'unitPrice' => 190,
    'cost' => 90,
    'trackStockLevel' => true,
    'isParentProduct' => false,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbdb',
    'name' => 'Long-sleeved shirt(sample)(M)',
    'tags' => 
    array (
      0 => 'tops',
      1 => 'cotton',
    ),
    'category' => 'Women\'s Apparel',
    'sku' => 'ABC1234-M',
    'priceType' => 'Fixed',
    'unitPrice' => 47.170000000000002,
    'cost' => 20,
    'trackStockLevel' => true,
    'isParentProduct' => false,
    'parentProductId' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbd4',
    'variationValues' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'variantGroupId' => '5db29b6d31c391731239bbd5',
        'value' => 'M',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add following if condition then it will check arr has low stock product then only it will send email and you can pass arr to email

```html
if(isset($arr) && is_array($arr) && sizeof($arr) > 0 )
        {
            $emailSubject = "Location A has items running low on stock";
            $emailContents = "Dear Operations Team, Location A is running low on these items:</br>" 
            Mail::to('asf@asf.com')->send(new \App\Mail\SendNotificationEmail($emailSubject, $emailContents, $theme,$arr));            }
```

Comment: the thing is, it will send a separate email for each product that has low stock. what i am trying to accomplish here is for all products that have a low stock be sent in the same email.